# FAQ how to Insert Images on comment

Tags: discussion, comments, images

I want to answer some questions through pictures, but don't know how to. I'm new to Stack Overflow. How can I insert images in the comment section?

Comment: 1) Such questions should be asked on meta.stackoverflow! 2) It is not a good practice to answer through pictures on that site. It is preferable to write some code. 3) I think it is impossible (denied) to insert images into comments, e.g. to prevent flooding.

Comment: like this http://i.imgur.com/wTrEucK.png and this http://i.stack.imgur.com/nakLN.gif and this http://i.stack.imgur.com/4A248.png

Answer (score 8):

You can not insert images on a comment. You can *link* to an image though.

If you need to insert an image on a post, you can following the instructions on [How to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

> #### Images
>
> Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button. This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard. Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link:
>
> ```
>    HTML <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
>    Markdown ![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)
> ```

Comment: Side note: the OP doesn't have enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: Markdown ![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)